# Exchange data between interactive_mode and script_mode?

Tags: python

Suppose to run a block of code in script_mode and produce such data:

```
my_data = [1, 2, 3, 4] #please note this is output after running not data in script
```

Now I switch to work in console for  debugging the code.
I need to use the data produced just now, while cannot copy directly for avoiding the effect of gibberish. 
My solution is to pickle first in the script_mode and unpickle it in interactive_mode:

Codes with 5 commands:

Script Mode

```
import pickle

with open('my_data','wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(my_data, file)
```

Interactive_mode:

```
import os, pickle
# change to the working directory
os.chdir('~\..\')
with open('my_data', 'rb') as file:
         my_data = pickle.load(file)
# my_data is finally loaded in console
# then manipulate it on the console.
```

How to do it in less steps?

Comment: By interactive, do you mean IDLE? The variable is available - I just checked.

Comment: Is it a scoped variable? Show relevant code.

Comment: I use macOS's terminal and atom editor.@aaronPlease read question.

Comment: Show relevant code of how the variable is scoped. Try creating a new file with `a = 1` and you should see that it's accessible.

Comment: Yes, the question is to check if `pickle` is the quickest method to process file. @aaron

Comment: Yes. But probably unnecessary in your case.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but if you use [ipython](https://ipython.org/index.html) instead of standard python IDLE, you can easily run a script an keep the objects (vars, functions, classes, etc.) defined in the script by running `%run -i script.py`. Then there's no need to pickle/unpickle stuff. BTW, I'm not talking about jupyter (formerly "ipython notebook"), but just ipython as an interactive shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the file with the `-i` option, like `python -i your_file_name.py`.

This will run your file first, then open an interactive shell with all of the variables present and ready for use.

Comment: `$ python3 -i divide_to_chapters.py` and call `>>> content_list` NameError: name 'content_list' is not defined

Comment: @DFK can't do much when I don't know what is `divide_to_chapters.py`

Answer (score 2):

If, in your `/path/to/your/project` directory, you have the script `your_script.py` like this:

```
my_data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you want to debug your script in a Python 2 interactive shell, you can do:

```
$ python
>>> execfile('/path/to/your/project/your_script.py')
```

Or, with the Python 2+3 way:

```
>>> exec(open('/path/to/your/project/your_script.py').read(), globals())
```

The built-in function [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) supports dynamic execution of Python code.
The built-in function [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) returns the current global dictionary.
That way you can access to your data:

```
>>> my_data
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: The data isn't in script, it's produced by implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use IPython, just:

```
pip install IPython
```

Then anywhere you want to drop into a console, simply

```
import IPython
```

at the top of the file and use:

```
IPython.embed()
```

where you'd like to drop in.

You can type "whos" once you're in for a list of variables alongside their type and values.  It's pretty useful, but yeah, this should work for you. IPython is a solid python shell.

You can also use ipdb if you're more used to the standard pdb.  It's really good too.

Comment: Could introduce a blog which specifying frequent usage of ipython in short content?

Comment: This is a series that should cover some of the basics of using IPython if that's what you're after.  Otherwise, I'm not sure I understand your question. http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html